# How to Scrape Dynamic Ice Condition Data from an ArcGIS Online Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, arcgis

I am trying to scrape publicly available ice condition data from a municipal website that uses an ArcGIS Online map to display this information. I would like to automate this data collection for personal use. I've previously scraped static websites using libraries like Cheerio and Axios, but I'm unsure how to proceed with a site that loads data dynamically.

The website is https://cartographie.ville.terrebonne.qc.ca/patin-exterieur/.

I've tried inspecting the Network tab in the browser's developer console to see if I can find any direct API calls but haven't had much success.

I'm considering using Selenium to simulate user interactions to fetch the data but wanted to check if there's a more efficient method to scrape this dynamic content.

Questions:

- Is it possible to scrape data from this type of ArcGIS map?
- If so, what libraries or technologies would you recommend?
- Are there any public APIs that I could use to collect this data more efficiently?

Any guidance or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[REST service containing map data from the municipal](https://cartographie.ville.terrebonne.qc.ca/arcgis/rest/services)

This is a link directly to the rest-service that provides data to the map and can be queried both dynamically via code or in the browser.

I am not a french speaker, so I am not exactly sure what data this includes. It should however include all the data used in the map.